# Android TextView append to the top

Tags: android, textview

Is there possibility to add text to the top of a `TextView`?

Comment: Sure... try `myText.setText("some other text\n" + myText.getText());`

Comment: Works! Write as an answer!

Comment: Did you have doubts? ;)

Comment: Well it is obvious, still first I just did implement it in my app anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Do so:

```
myText.setText("some other text\n" + myText.getText());
```